System.JSONException: was expecting double-quote to start field name at [line:2, column:5] (System Code)
This is my request body in json format:
{
   “Client65_ID": "0006HD24K6",
   “Company76_Code": "87C”,
   “Role65": "Project Manager"
}

My Apex code:
@RestResource(urlMapping='/AccountInfo/*')
global with sharing class AccountInfoService {
    
    @HttpPost
    global static void postChatterMessage() {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        
        String requestBody = req.requestBody.toString();
        Map<String, Object> requestMap = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(requestBody);
        
        //storing requestBody parameters
        String clientId = (String) requestMap.get('Client65_ID');
        String companyCode = (String)requestMap.get('Company76_Code');
        String role = (String)requestMap.get('Role65');

        try{
            //Fetch the Account record and corresponding Account Team Member record
            Account account = [SELECT Id,Client65_ID,Company76_Code,Region__c,Name
                           FROM Account
                           WHERE Client65_ID = :clientId
                           AND Company76_Code = :companyCode
                           LIMIT 1];
            
            Account_Team__c atm = [SELECT Id, Status__c
                           FROM Account_Team__c
                           WHERE Account__c = :account.Id
                           AND Role65 = :role
                           AND Status__c = 'Active'
                           LIMIT 1][0];
       
            
            //Post Chatter Message
        
            ConnectApi.FeedItemInput feedItemInput = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();
            ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput mentionSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput();
            ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput messageBodyInput = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();
            ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();

            messageBodyInput.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>();

            textSegmentInput.text = 'Hi ';
            messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(textSegmentInput);

            mentionSegmentInput.username = atm.Id;
            messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(mentionSegmentInput);
            
            textSegmentInput.text = '\n\nThis Account is ready for Implementation\n\nAccount Details: \nClient ID: '+ clientId +'\nCompany Code: '+ companyCode +'\nAuto Pay Region : ' + account.Region__c  +'\nName: '+ account.Name;
           
            messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(textSegmentInput);
            feedItemInput.body = messageBodyInput;
            feedItemInput.subjectId = '001DK000012x23pYAA';
            
            ConnectApi.FeedElement feedElement = ConnectAPI.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement(null,feedItemInput);
            
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('Success');
            
        } catch (QueryException qe) {
            res.statusCode = 404;
            res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('Error: No matching records found.');
        } catch (Exception e) {
            res.statusCode = 500;
            res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('Error: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
        
    }
}


You have so-called "smart" quotes (“ and ”) interspersed in your json string. That's the issue.
The JSON RFC, section 7 requires that only "straight" double quotes (a.k.a. quotation marks, ", ASCII 0x22) be used for strings, and field names are strings, so Salesforce's JSON functionality expects that as well.
Make sure that the JSON you're passing into Salesforce is valid (no personal affiliation to that link), and that particular error will disappear.
